# right alignment HTML email

Tags: html, email, html-email

I'm trying to align a white block with round corners to the right in an email that has 4 columns. I'm pretty new to this, so any help would be appreciated. At the minute it's just automatically algin to the left but I don't know why.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v96fE.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide a snippet of your code. Very difficult seeing what you're looking for from the screenshots. Actually looks as though there are more issues going by the white edges on the block, rather than a full white background. But...Hard to tell without any code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

James, you can try adding `float: right` to your child element CSS